# Yosys: how to convert D-latches to FFs and LUTs?

Tags: fpga, synthesis, yosys

I want to synthesis a design that has latches into a set of primitives (only FFs and LUTs are supported)
I am expecting a switch similar to dff_legalize.

If not possible should I change the RTL?

I have blocks like:
always @(state1 or state2)
begin

do something
end

Comment: It seems that clk2fflogic resolved the issue.